# SQLalchemy reflecting table with json column issue

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to use sqlalchemy to interact with a mysql database (Singlestore). On my initial table that contains ints/strings everything works fine. However I have a table with json columns that sqlalchemy fails to reflect. I am given the error below.

> SAWarning: Did not recognize type 'JSON' of column
>
> TypeError: NullType() takes no arguments

```
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from sqlalchemy.orm import class_mapper
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy import and_
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import insert
from helpers.sqlalchemy_connector import SessionManager, engine


class DatabaseOperations(SessionManager):
    def _get_table(self, table_name):
        return self.Base.classes.get(table_name)

    def _object_to_dict(self, obj):
        return {c.key: getattr(obj, c.key) for c in class_mapper(obj.__class__).columns}

    def _reflect_table(self, table_name):
        self.metadata = MetaData()
        self.metadata.reflect(engine, only=[table_name])
        self.Base = automap_base(metadata=self.metadata)
        self.Base.prepare()

    def query_table(self, table_name, filters=None, limit=None, offset=None):
        self._reflect_table(table_name)

        if filters is None:
            filters = []

        TableModel = self._get_table(table_name)
        query = self.session.query(TableModel)

        if filters:
            filter_conditions = []
            for column_name, filter_value in filters.items():
                if hasattr(TableModel, column_name):
                    column = getattr(TableModel, column_name)
                    filter_conditions.append(column == filter_value)
            if filter_conditions:
                query = query.filter(and_(*filter_conditions))

        if limit:
            query = query.limit(limit)

        if offset:
            query = query.offset(offset)

        result_objects = query.all()

        result_dicts = [self._object_to_dict(obj) for obj in result_objects]
        self.session.close()
        return result_dicts

    def save_to_table(self, table_name, data_dict):
        self._reflect_table(table_name)
        TableModel = self._get_table(table_name)
        inserted_data = {}

        # Use insert().values() to generate the INSERT statement
        insert_stmt = insert(TableModel).values(**data_dict)

        # Use on_duplicate_key_update() to generate the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement
        on_duplicate_key_stmt = insert_stmt.on_duplicate_key_update(**data_dict)

        # Execute the upsert statement
        db_result = self.session.execute(on_duplicate_key_stmt)
        self.session.commit()

        # Fetch the data that was just inserted
        if db_result:
            filters = db_result.inserted_primary_key._mapping
            inserted_record_list = self.query_table(table_name, filters=filters)

        inserted_data = inserted_record_list[0] if inserted_record_list else {}

        self.session.close()
        return inserted_data
```

I am calling the save_to_table method but it is failing in the self.metadata.reflect() part.

```
def log_payload(req_body, res_body, headers, api_path):
    req_body_payload = json.loads(req_body) if req_body else None
    res_body_response = json.loads(res_body) if res_body else None

    log_payload = {
        "payload": req_body_payload,
        "response": res_body_response,
        "headers": headers,
        "api_path": api_path,
    }

    db_instance.save_to_table(table_name="log_payloads", data_dict=log_payload)
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? I really want to stick to using the existing automap feature. I do not want to have to declare possibly hundreds of tables with hundreds of columns.

Here is my sql table DDL

```
-- motor_dba.log_payloads definition
CREATE ROWSTORE TABLE `log_payloads` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  `payload` JSON COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `response` JSON COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `headers` JSON COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `api_path` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) AUTO_INCREMENT=27021597764222999 AUTOSTATS_CARDINALITY_MODE=OFF AUTOSTATS_HISTOGRAM_MODE=OFF SQL_MODE='STRICT_ALL_TABLES';
```